# Order of magnitude of this phase space invariant?

Tags: general-relativity

So I wanted know the order of magnitude of this phase [space invariant](http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/1203.1.K.pdf) (equation $3.31a$ )$R$  [in our universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) (FLRW metric):

$$R = \int_{p} \frac{\mathcal{N}(x,p,t)}{\mathcal{E}} dp_x dp_y dp_z$$

where $\mathcal{N}(x,p,t)$ is the phase space distribution of matter in our universe, $\mathcal{E}= p_0$ is the energy and $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ are the spatial momentum.

One can assume low energy and temperature limit (also assume the formation of the molecules has taken place)? What is it's observed value?

Comment: Is $R \sim 10^7$ or $R\sim 10^6$ in SI units?

Comment: What is $R$ physically?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin "This is the sum, over all particles
in a unit 3-volume, of the inverse energy. "

Comment: Might be better to ask on physics SE